# How do I send images and text on the same Java socket?

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I am new to java, and a bit stuck on my media control project. What I need to do is send images and text to a client application. I have found some example code of receiving an image and displaying it (listed below). This works really well, but I need to have a way of sending an image and text down the same socket connection.

Its there a way of deciding what type of data it is? I want it to my program to display it if it is an image, and show a msgbox if it is text.

Should I have two sockets, one for images and one for text?

Unfortunately the variable names in the sample code are not english which makes it a little harder to follow:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Cliente extends JFrame {

  JTextField tf;
  Lienzo lienzo;
  Socket con;
  ObjectOutputStream salida;
  ObectInputStream entrada;

  public Cliente(){

    super("Cliente");
    Container c = getContentPane();

    tf = new JTextField(10);
    lienzo = new Lienzo();

    c.add(lienzo);
    pack();
    setSize(100,100);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  void ejecutar(){

    try{

      con = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5700);
      salida = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
      salida.flush();
      entrada = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());

      procesar();

    }
    catch(IOException e){}

  }

  void procesar() throws IOException {

    try{

      while(true){
        ImageIcon img = (ImageIcon) entrada.readObject();
        escribir(img);
      }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}

  }

  void escribir(final ImageIcon img){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
      new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
          lienzo.pinta(img);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  public static void main( String args[] ){
    Cliente cl = new Cliente();
    cl.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cl.ejecutar();
  }

  class Lienzo extends JPanel{

    ImageIcon img = null ;

    public Lienzo(){

    }

    public void pinta(ImageIcon img){
      this.img = img;
      repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

      super.paintComponent(g);

      if(img!=null)
        img.paintIcon(this,g,10,10);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have control of both server and client then a very simple way would be to define classes for the different messages you want to send and then use object output/input streams to do the heavy lifting, aka marshaling.

Heres some wishy-washy pseudo-code:

```
class Message<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private T payload;

    public Message() {
            super();
    }

    public Message(T data) {
            super();
            setPayload(data);
    }

    public T getPayload() {
            return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(T aPayload) {
            payload = aPayload;
    }
}
```

On server:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(...);
oos.writeObject(new Message<String>("Hello World"));
```

On client:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(...);
Message<?> msg = (Message<?>) ois.readObject();
if(msg.getPayload() instanceof String) // do one thing
else if(msg.getPayload() instanceof Image) // do some other thing
```

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about sending multiple types of data across a socket. At this point, you may have to redesign your application. Instead of sending `ImageIcon` object through the socket you may send a different object (you will have to create your own class like below )

```
public class ImageAndText implements Serializable{
        String text;
        ImageIcon image;
 // and so on...
}
```

- This image and text object can have a `String` attribute that represents your text and `ImageIcon` attribute that represants your image. At the client end (in your `procesar()` method, read an `ImageAndText` type of object and get individual attributes and display them.

Answer (score 0):

You may use TLV (tag/length/value). One byte for the tag, two or more bytes for the length, depending on the maximum size of the text or image, and so on.